# My button is printed awkwardly

Tags: html, css

1. I have a table in which I am printing a button at the end of each row. I wish this button to be small.
2. And my text is not getting truncated when the table is printed despite using overflow ellipsis. I don't want the horizontal scroll bar.
3. My title bar of the table, the topmost row is always getting hidden as I scroll down.

[image: img]

Any help is much appreciated. Here is my **CSS** script https://jsfiddle.net/v6sahfyc/1/

Edit: Adding the php code here:

```
// <?php   
    // echo "<div id='awesometable'>"; 
// ?>

<!-- <CAPTION>RESERVATION TABLE</CAPTION> -->
<?php   

    echo "<br><br><p style=\"font-family:verdana; font-size:100%; margin-left: 5em;\"><i><strong>Reservation Table.</strong></i></p>";
    echo "<table id='reservation' class='inlineTable'>";  //style='border: solid 1px black;'
    //echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-1 uid\">UserId</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-2 rname\">Resource <br> Name</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-3 rtype\">Resource <br> Type</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-4 rloc\">Resource <br> Location</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-5 treq\">Time <br> Required </th>";
    echo "<th class=\"row-6 REM\">Delete? </th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    //echo "</thead>\n";            
    //echo "<col = width: 3em />";
?>
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";

    $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Unable to connect");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("mydb", $connector) or die("Unable to connect");
    $selectSQL = "SELECT  user_ID, ResourceName, ResourceType, ResourceLocation, ReservationTime FROM reservation_table";
    if( !( $selectRes = mysql_query( $selectSQL ) ) ){
        echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
    }else{
?>
<tbody>
<?php
        if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){

        }else{
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
              echo "<tr><td>{$row['user_ID']}</td><td>{$row['ResourceName']}</td><td>{$row['ResourceType']}</td><td>{$row['ResourceLocation']}</td><td>{$row['ReservationTime']}</td>";
              $active = $_SESSION['usr'] == $row['user_ID'];
              echo "<td>"."<button class='btn' type='submit' id='1'".($active ? "" : "disabled").">"."Delete"."</button>"."</td>";
            }
        }               
?>      
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
        mysql_close($connector);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you can't run php code in a fiddle.

Comment: I know, sorry,.. I just pasted it there because I didn't know of a fiddle which allows me to paste php and put screenshot of my table, so that you could see what's wrong with my table.

Comment: the problem is this makes your code very hard to read and the fiddle hard to update, also it looks like you might be missing styles comparing the fiddle to your screenshot. Can you please add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Ok, I just added my PHP code that makes the table. I am reading some data from my database and then printing them to my table. *(Yes, I know PDO is the correct way to connect and my method is deprecated, sorry about that)*

Comment: Is there a reason why you are escaping the quotes in your html?

Comment: @Chris : I only escaped the quotes for the html that were inside the quotes for the PHP echo statement I believe. I thought that was necessary, to avoid the syntax error?